# How to convert part of an expression to string?

Tags: evaluation

I'm trying to generate some code. I'm trying:

```
ToString[CompoundExpression[Unevaluated@Import["MyModule"], expressionThatIsGenerated]]
```

expecting output like:

```
Import["MyModule"];
expressionThatIsGenerated
```

So, I want to output `Import["MyModule"]` unevaluated, but it doesn't work - `Import["MyModule"]` gets evaluated to `expressionThatIsGenerated` every time.

(Use case):

I'm going through Mathematica documentation notebooks and generating test cases (for checking compatibility of open source Mathematica implementations with original) out of them. See:

https://github.com/darvin/MMATestSuiteGenerator

After I'm finished with a notebook, my `expressionThatIsGenerated` looks like:

```
ESimpleExamples[EComment["Test if an expression is an integer:"], 
 ESameTest[MatchQ[12345, _Integer], True], 
 EComment["Test if an expression is a sum of two or more terms:"], 
 ESameTest[MatchQ[(x - 1)*(1 + 2*x + 3*x^2), _ + __], False]]
```

naturally I wanna record it into a file, with prepended `Import["FileThatDefinesMyTestFrameworkFunctions"];`, like that:

```
Import["FileThatDefinesMyTestFrameworkFunctions"];
ESimpleExamples[EComment["Test if an expression is an integer:"], 
 ESameTest[MatchQ[12345, _Integer], True], 
 EComment["Test if an expression is a sum of two or more terms:"], 
 ESameTest[MatchQ[(x - 1)*(1 + 2*x + 3*x^2), _ + __], False]]
```

Comment: Evaluating `CompoundExpression` throws away all its arguments except the last.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to achieve here. I cannot imagine a situation where this would be useful. Could you expand on the actual problem you are trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: I also don't fully understand the use case, but would something like this work for you?  ```Attributes[toString] = HoldAllComplete; toString[CompoundExpression[args__]] := With[
  {strings = ToString[Unevaluated[#], InputForm] & /@ {args}},
  StringRiffle[strings, ";\n"]
  ]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If exporting to a file is your only concern, why not use the `"HeldExpressions"` element of the [`"Package"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Package.html) `Export` format? This allows you to give a list of `HoldComplete[…]` expressions that should be exported, making it unnecessary to manually handle removal of some kind of hold wrapper.

```
SetDirectory@CreateDirectory[]

expr = x^2 + 1/2;

Export["test.m", {HoldComplete[Import["MyModule"];], HoldComplete@#&@expr}, "HeldExpressions"]
(* "test.m" *)

Import["test.m", "String"]
(* "(* Created with the Wolfram Language *)

Import[\"MyModule\"]; 

1/2 + x^2

" *)
```

Answer (score 2):

@John gave a method using [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm), but this only works with single argument [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString) (which uses [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm)). Single argument [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString) can do horrible things like:

```
ToString[x^2+1/2]

(*
1    2
- + x
2
*)
```

which certainly can not be reevaluated. It is better to use `ToString[expr, InputForm]`, e.g.:

```
ToString[x^2+1/2, InputForm]
```

> 1/2 + x^2

However, [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm) is not invisible when using [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm):

```
ToString[HoldForm[x^2+1/2], InputForm]
```

> HoldForm[x^2 + 1/2]

My preferred method to achieve a [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm)-like construct within [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) is to temporarily give the function [`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm) a [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll) attribute. For example:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{SequenceForm},
    SetAttributes[SequenceForm, HoldAll];
    ToString[SequenceForm[x^2+1+1], InputForm]
]
```

> x^2 + 1 + 1

For your question, then, we could do:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{SequenceForm},
    SetAttributes[SequenceForm, HoldAll];
    ToString[
        SequenceForm @ CompoundExpression[
            Import["MyModule"],
            expressionThatIsGenerated
        ],
        InputForm
    ]
]
```

> Import["MyModule"]; expressionThatIsGenerated

Answer (score 1):

`Unevaluated` is a quote that disappears to the evaluator after its first evaluation. I think you want `HoldForm`, which disappears from the string representation, but otherwise persists. Then, you can inject the evaluated expression into the held expression with a replacement.

```
ToString[HoldForm[CompoundExpression[Import["MyModule"], etig]] /. 
  etig -> expressionThatIsGenerated]
```